# Node ExpressJS Routes issue in routing

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, express-generator

I am using express-generator to generate the basic routes.

Here is what i have so far in routes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrl = require('../controller/index');
var validation = require("../validations/user");
/* GET home page. */
router.route('/').get(ctrl.index);
router.route('/registerUser').post(validation.registerUser,ctrl.registerUser);
```

It is working fine.

After i add the below routes

```
router.route('/loginUser').post(validation.loginUser,ctrl.loginUser);
module.exports = router;
```

i am getting error like

```
opt/lampp/htdocs/MedApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:171
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/MedApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:171:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

How can i allow more routes in the routes.js file ?

Help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have not exported ctrl.registerUser function in index.js.

Make sure you have something like this

in validation/user.js

```
exports.registerUser=function(req,res,next){...};

exports.loginUser=function(req,res,next){...};
```

in controller/index.js

```
exports.registerUser=function(req,res){...};

exports.loginUser=function(req,res){...};
```

Comment: Thanks, but inside the function .. how can i have the logic to call the controller .. i.e., `validation.registerUser,ctrl.registerUser` ?

Comment: which function are u talking about ?

Comment: I need to call the `ctrl.registerUser` once i hit the registerUser

Comment: in validation.registerUser , if validation success call next();

Comment: Here is my controller file.. if you need to see it https://jsfiddle.net/yh3a7gpx/

Comment: Do i need to change anything inside the routes ?

Comment: are u using mongoose?

Comment: Yes am using mongoose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124860/discussion-between-sa-and-anshuman-singh).

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `Route.post() requires a callback`.

You have:

```
router.route('/loginUser').post(validation.loginUser,ctrl.loginUser);
```

Use a callback function like so:

```
router.post('/loginUser', function(req, res) {
     //run your loginUser logic here
});

module.exports = router; //make this file available to other files
```

Comment: It works, but how can i have the `validation.registerUser,ctrl.registerUser` inside it ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Can you clarify? That code doesn't look quite right. You can run these functions `validation.registerUser` `ctrl.registerUser` inside the callback function.

Comment: In this way `router.route('/loginUser').post(validation.loginUser,ctrl.loginUser);` i can able to call the `loginUser` function inside the controller which is invoked. But in the way you stated. How can i do that ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code. Try copying and pasting the code in  files: `/controller/index /validations/user`